# Highlighting rows and columns for zebra tables in IE8 too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is a problem with MSIE by trying to select row and column by hover a table cell of a zebra striped table. I want to use jQuery, but if I find any possibility in any Javascript I be in better mood. Without the zebra effect I found this:

```
<style>
.hilite { background: #fda; }
td:hover { background: #EEE;}
</style>

html:
<table id="tab">
<colgroup><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /></colgroup>
<tr><td>When</td><td>a</td><td>problem</td><td>comes</td><td>along,</td></tr>
<tr><td>you</td><td>a</td><td>whip</td><td>it</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Before the</td><td>cream</td><td>stays</td><td>out too</td><td>long</td></tr>
<tr><td>you</td><td>must</td><td>whip it</td><td>When</td><td>something's</td></tr>
<tr><td>going</td><td>a</td><td>you</td><td>must</td><td>whip it</td></tr>
</table>

script:
$(function(){
$("td").hover(function(){
$("#tab col").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hilite");
$(this).closest("tr").addClass("hilite");
},function(){
$("#tab col").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hilite");
$(this).closest("tr").removeClass("hilite");
});
});
```

[to find an example here:](http://jsbin.com/ocafu3)

But works not with an zebra effect together.

[a further example here](http://jsbin.com/zitun/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: set a conditional rule for IE8 to put the background on `<td>`

Comment: with: $("#tab col").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hilite"); I don't change the background of the td tag? How can I do that in better way for the cols?

Comment: can use an IE conditional comment with a style tag in it or an IE specific style sheet with that rule in it